# Cannot initialize microphone. Speech recognition disabled

Tags: java, voice-recognition, microphone

I was trying something very basic using the Voce API on Java:

```
public class Vocetest {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpeechInterface.init("C:\\Users\\Ahmed Akabawi\\Desktop\\voce-0.9.1\\lib",true,true,"C:\\Users\\Ahmed Akabawi\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Vocetest\\vocabulary.txt",""); 

  SpeechInterface.setRecognizerEnabled(true);
 while (SpeechInterface.getRecognizerQueueSize() > 0)
    {
         SpeechInterface.setRecognizerEnabled(true);
  String s = voce.SpeechInterface.popRecognizedString();
  System.out.println("You said: " + s);
    }
}
```

what I get is

```
[Voce] Initializing synthesizer
[Voce] Initializing recognizer. This may take some time...
[Voce] No grammar file specified.  Defaulting to 'digits.gram'
[Voce] Initialization complete
[Voce warning] Cannot initialize microphone. Speech recognition disabled.
```

The microphone cannot be initialized. However I have tested it, and it is working.

What should I do ?